# AWS Java SDK - Running a command using SSM on EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

I could not find any examples of this online, nor could I find the documentation explaining how to do this. Basically I have a list of **Windows** EC2 instances and I need to run the `quser` command in each one of them to check how many users are logged on.

It is possible to do this using the **AWS Systems Manager** service and running the **AWS-RunPowerShellScript** command. I only found examples using the **AWS CLI**, something like this:

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "instance ID" --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" --comment "Get Users" --parameters commands=quser --output text
```

**But how can I accomplish this using the AWS Java SDK 1.11.x ?**

Comment: You can use `Waiter` logic if in SDKV2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Alexandre Krabbe it's more than a year before you asked this question. So not sure the answer will help you. But I was trying to do the same recently and that led me to this unanswered question. I ended up solving the problem and thought my answer could help other people facing the same problem. Here is a code snippet for the same:

```
public void runCommand() throws InterruptedException {
    //Command to be run
    String ssmCommand = "ls -l";
    Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(){{
        put("commands", new ArrayList<String>(){{ add(ssmCommand); }});
    }};
    int timeoutInSecs = 5;
    //You can add multiple command ids separated by commas
    Target target = new Target().withKey("InstanceIds").withValues("instance-id");
    //Create ssm client.
    //The builder could be chosen as per your preferred way of authentication
    //use withRegion for specifying your region
    AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssm = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard().build();
    //Build a send command request
    SendCommandRequest commandRequest = new SendCommandRequest()
            .withTargets(target)
            .withDocumentName("AWS-RunShellScript")
            .withParameters(params);
    //The result has commandId which is used to track the execution further
    SendCommandResult commandResult = ssm.sendCommand(commandRequest);
    String commandId = commandResult.getCommand().getCommandId();
    //Loop until the invocation ends
    String status;
    do {
        ListCommandInvocationsRequest request = new ListCommandInvocationsRequest()
                .withCommandId(commandId)
                .withDetails(true);
        //You get one invocation per ec2 instance that you added to target
        //For just a single instance use get(0) else loop over the instanced
        CommandInvocation invocation = ssm.listCommandInvocations(request).getCommandInvocations().get(0);
        status = invocation.getStatus();
        if(status.equals("Success")) {
            //command output holds the output of running the command
            //eg. list of directories in case of ls
            String commandOutput = invocation.getCommandPlugins().get(0).getOutput();
            //Process the output
        }
        //Wait for a few seconds before you check the invocation status again
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(timeoutInSecs);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //Handle not being able to sleep
        }
    } while(status.equals("Pending") || status.equals("InProgress"));
    if(!status.equals("Success")) {
        //Command ended up in a failure
    }
}
```

Comment: String commandOutput = invocation.getCommandPlugins().get(0).getOutput();

Seems to return only the Error window output.

Anyway to get the actually output?

Answer (score 0):

In SDK 1.11.x , use sth like:

```
val waiter = ssmClient.waiters().commandExecuted()

waiter.run(WaiterParameters(GetCommandInvocationRequest()
    .withCommandId(commandId)
    .withInstanceId(instanceId)
))
```